# How to add multi part config using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipart

I'm trying to send multi-part file to a controller using **Spring** and when I post my data to the URL I get this error :

> Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided.

I have searched absolutely everywhere and my problem is still pending... I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is some of my code :

**Upload Controller**

```
@Controller
public class UploadController {

        @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String provideUploadInfo() {
        return "You can upload a file by posting to this same URL.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, Principal principal){


        User activeUser = principal == null ? null
                : (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();


       return "whatever";
    }
}
```

**Application-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

It seems that I have the whole inclusions I needed to put. I'm running this app on a Tomcat 8 server.

**EDIT**

Following the tips given  by  Sotirios Delimanolis and zeroflagL, my code was updated.

I've made several tests and when I'm trying to upload a bigger file than the limit allows, I get this :

> Maximum upload size of 100000 bytes exceeded; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (229305) exceeds the configured maximum (100000)

That means the `multipartResolver` was successfully reached, isn't it ?

However, I'm still getting the ***no multi-part config file provided*** error. How could that be possible ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Get rid of the `@MultipartConfig` annotation on your `@Controller` class. It serves no purpose there.

Comment: Ok thanks but can you tell me why ?
I thought `@MultipartConfig` was used to indicate that the servlet on which it is declared expects requests to made using the multipart/form-data MIME. And you could use some specifics methods like `getParts()` to retrieve parts file.

Comment: `UploadController` is not a servlet. Did you include the necessary dependency?

Comment: Coule you give me more information ? That's the way I write my controllers (dispatchers), what's wrong with that ? Also, if your talking about the Common Multiparts Resolver jar, yes it is included.

Comment: `@MultipartConfig` is a servlet annotation, not a controller annotation. Spring will ignore it.